# convert timestamp into a particular format?

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

i want to convert timestamp into this format `20 dec 2019 10:10 AM`.
i have an array of object so i have implemented this code regarding that

```js
var data =[
  {
    report: 'xyz',
    office: 'ccc.xbx',
    timestamp: 1576023365640,
    officeId: 'ttttttt',
    month: 3,
    year: 2019
  },
  {
    report: 'yyy',
    totalUsers: 1288,
    office: 'yyyy.in',
    timestamp: 1576023365640,
    officeId: 'prfzIYlOkAw3gqc03yszttffffdddaq',
    date: 24,
    month: 10,
    year: 2019
  },
  {
    report: 'xyz',
    office: 'ccc.xbx',
    timestamp: 1576023365640,
    officeId: 'DZxUwW9TzbwCYNclYLgE',
    month: 3,
    year: 2019
  },
  {
    report: 'xyz',
    office: 'ccc.xbx',
    timestamp: 1576023365640,
    officeId: 'DZxUwW9TzbwCYNclYLgE',
    month: 3,
    year: 2019
  }
]
data.forEach(function(itm) {
    itm.timestamp = moment(itm.timestamp).format("LLL");
    console.log(itm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

expected output in this format for a particular timestamp

```
20 dec 2019 10:10 AM
```

Comment: `moment(+itm.timestamp).format("LLL");` don't use string timestamp, it has to be `int`, output format `December 11, 2019 5:46 AM`

Comment: Just use `.format('DD MMM YYYY hh:mm A')`.

Comment: @siddhantsankhe—the timestamp **is** a number. It doesn't have to be an integer.

Comment: @RobG before editing this question , the timestamp was stored as `string` which on format will give `"Invalid Date"`

Answer (score 0):

Modified the below code:

```
itm.timestamp = moment(+itm.timestamp).format("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm A");
```

The `+` sign converts the `string` into an `integer` which can then be passed to `moment()`. And then using the `format()` to arrange output as per your requirement.

**Full Solution Snippet:**

```js
var data =[
  {
    report: 'xyz',
    office: 'ccc.xbx',
    timestamp: '1576023365640',
    officeId: 'ttttttt',
    month: 3,
    year: 2019
  },
  {
    report: 'yyy',
    totalUsers: 1288,
    office: 'yyyy.in',
    timestamp: '1576023365640',
    officeId: 'prfzIYlOkAw3gqc03yszttffffdddaq',
    date: 24,
    month: 10,
    year: 2019
  },
  {
    report: 'xyz',
    office: 'ccc.xbx',
    timestamp: '1576023365640',
    officeId: 'DZxUwW9TzbwCYNclYLgE',
    month: 3,
    year: 2019
  },
  {
    report: 'xyz',
    office: 'ccc.xbx',
    timestamp: '1576023365640',
    officeId: 'DZxUwW9TzbwCYNclYLgE',
    month: 3,
    year: 2019
  }
]
data.forEach(function(itm) {
    itm.timestamp = moment(+itm.timestamp).format("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm A");
    console.log(itm);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The format should be "DD MMM YYYY hh:mm A". HH is 24 hour and MM is two digit month.